# How to log using Winston/NextJS and API routes?

Tags: logging, next.js, winston

My requirement is quite simple, but as I'm new to modern JS frameworks like Next.js, I could use some guidance.

My goal is to log specific key actions that users take on my website. To achieve this, I've already created a logger.js file where I configured my logger object using Winston. Additionally, I've implemented an API function to log the contents to a file, and it's functioning as expected.

However, I'm facing an issue with calling this method from my JS UI files. Currently, when I use `router.push` to call the API, the website redirects to the API page. I want to find a way to invoke the logging API without triggering a redirection, allowing the website to continue with the next steps.

If anyone has experience with this or knows a better/right way to accomplish this, I would greatly appreciate your insights.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`router.push()` is solely used for client-side navigation, not API calls.

To call an API you would need to use the `fetch` function as follows

```
const res = fetch('/api/your-route', {
   method: 'POST', // change based on your request type.
   body: JSON.stringify(data) // if you have data to pass
}
```

Now inside the `/api/your-route/` folder, create a new file called `route.js` and transfer your API logic in here as follows:

```
export async function POST(req) {
  const data = await req.json() // to receive data
 // TODO: your API logic
 // note the name of the function must be the same as your method passed in
 // the fetch request that was made from the client side.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should have mentioned that I am on Next v12.3.4. Hasn't route.js been introduced from v13?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. I was able to get this to work for v12.3.4.